# Java Jenetics lib. Fitness progress stops in the first few generations

Tags: java, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, jenetics

I am trying to solve a problem using a genetic algorithm:

- A gene stores ints approximately in the range of 0 to 500.
- The size of one genotype is approximately in the range of 10 to 10000.
- This genotype looks like: [13, 476, 3, 89...]
- The population of one generation is 100.
- The number of generations is 10000.
- I made a fitness function. It gives a score in the range of 0 to 1 (type double).

## First try

I wrote my *genetic algorithm*. I wrote it as simply as possible, because I was not sure that it would work at all.

With these parameters, it gives a result of approximately **0.91** fitness. This is a good result, but I'm sure that I can achieve a result of at least **0.97** fitness.
But my algorithm is starting to lose performance. He continues to improve the result, but the progress of this improvement is extremely slow.

## Second try

I decided to try something different. Using my fitness function I implemented *Jenetics library* with all by default and population = 100. The genotype is the same as in the first case.

10000 generations gave a result of about **0.27** fitness. At the same time, the fitness of the first generation is approximately **0.20-0.23**. And he reaches the result of **0.27** fitness in about 100 generations, after which **progress stops**.

## Question

Why? All parameters are by default, I did not change anything at all (except for the population size).
What have I done wrong? Please explain and tell me what parameters should be given to this library. I'm not very good at genetic algorithms.

The problem is that **progress is not moving** at all. In my algorithm, it moves, slowly but surely.

I tried changing offspringSelector(). I tried different ones with different values. In my algorithm, I use something similar to EliteSelector(1).
I tried changing alterers(). Here too I have tried various combinations of classes with different values. In my algorithm, I use something similar to SinglePointCrossover(1) + Mutator(0.1).

I have no need to repeat my algorithm. I want to achieve a similar result using the *Jenetics* implementation.
Or at least for fitness to just start growing, and **not stop at the very beginning**.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, without example code its very hard to give any advice ;-)